# Getting "Gradle sync failed: Please use JDK 8 or newer" under version 3.3

Tags: android-studio

I checked every thread related to that error. But I couldn't find the appropriate answer. I have additional error too. Check out the screenshots.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: So, did you install JDK8  ?

Comment: Yes !!  i installed it .I also made one app but i dont know after i mainpulated the paths in cmd for jdbc practice ...this happened:(

Comment: Seems your Android Studio is corrupted. You'd better re-install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts I came across recommending fixing JDK pathing issues through "Switch IDE book JDK..." or "Project Structure".

For me, in Android Studio 3.0, "Project Structure" would no longer open, so I upgraded to 3.1. Afterwards, it still had the JDK version error, but now it let me open "Project Structure" from the "File" menu, where I was able to correct the JDK, SDK, and NDK locations and versions.

There were still several build errors after that, but clicking the recommended fix in the build output window eventually installed everything I needed. Once it managed to synchronize correctly, it also upgraded Gradle to version 4.4. That then required new build tools and so forth.

Though instructions directly, may not help everyone, but it points to configuration corruption. So, if you cannot just upgrade to get around it, I recommend making backup copies of your Android Studio settings (generally in your user's home directory like `~/.AndroidStudioX.Y`), as well as your project `.idea` (generally in the root of your project), then deleting the originals. If that is still not enough, purge the configurations again and reinstall Android Studio.

*Note: I was going back into an old project so several warnings about deprecated features being removed in 2018 had to be dealt with.*

Comment: Deleting the configurations in question then relaunching Android Studio worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

[error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY0gC.jpg) 
Here's what worked for me! 
1. First verify that your JDK is indeed higher than JDK8

[jdk version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VxK5.jpg)
2. Press "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S" to open project structure 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDN24.jpg)
3. Then I selected "Use the embedded JDK"
4. Click OK and retry it.
That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem, getting these two kinda errors:

1. SDK path should not contain white space.
2. Gradle sync failed. Please use JDK 8 or newer.

Solution for me was to set proper SDK path with **no white space in path** first and than choose JDK path. After setting path I've synced the project and tada it worked...

Thanks.